# Android Trouble with RecyclerView and Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm using a recyclerview in my app, it works, but there 2-3 things I don't understand.

Firstly, why getItemCount is called few times ? When I set a log in this function, I can see 7 times my log.

Secondly, when I set my adapter, and I define my recyclerview, I'm doing something just after like that :

```
initAdapter();
initRecycler();
initSomething();
```

The function initSomething is called whereas initRecycler didn't load my items. (I can see with logs that the adapter do his job after initSomething...)

Someone to help/explain me ?

EDIT :

```
protected void initRecyclerView() {
    this.recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    this.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    this.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}
```

Comment: Post the body of the functions as well.. Just because the function is called doesn't mean it will work as you intend..

Comment: My adapter has nothing special, I followed https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html to do it and I edited my post for the function initRecycler().